# asp.net vb - update database field value automatically when another value is added elsewhere

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, linq-to-sql

I have two tables: HolidayRequests & HolidayEntitlement

Within the Holiday Requests I have 1 field:

- Days

When a staff member adds a holiday request it is stored as a number in the holiday requests table in days field (there are multiple requests with different days)

Within the HolidayEntitlement table I have 3 fields:

- Entitlement
- Taken
- Remaining

When a staff member adds a holiday request I want it to update both the taken and Remaining with something like...

Taken = (sum)Days where staffid = staffid

Remaining = Entitlement - Taken

I've got no idea how to go about doing this. The idea is similar to that of stock management...
can anyone point me in the right direction so I can get started

Comment: What database are you using? I've had experience implementing this but with SQL Server -- using Triggers. Maybe this will help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement business logic like that:

- in the database with triggers (see the other answers)
- in your vb code with Linq2sql using Partial Methods:

Example from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546176.aspx

```
Partial Class Customer
    Private Sub OnAddressChanged()
        ' Insert business logic here.
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use a stored procedure & issue a transaction whenever the parent field is updated
2. Use a trigger to fire on every insert/update on parent table row & update the 2nd table